# DB2 equivalent of SQLPlus

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I need a SQL-type interface for an existing DB2 database, similar to SQLPlus for Oracle (I actually use Golden for Oracle) on windows.

Can someone recommend something?

I've actually installed a 32-bit DB2 client from work which installed *many* programs but I have no idea which of these programs - if any - is the right one. Installed were: command editor, command line processor plus, command line processor, command window - administrator, command window, control center, journal, license center, replication center, task center, information center v9.7, activity monitor, event analyzer, health center, indoubt transaction manager, memory visualizer, configuration assistant, default db2 and database client selection wizard (no this isn't it, I thought it would be) and first steps.

All I want is a simple client to run SQL statements.

Answer (score 2):

Beginning with DB2 for LUW 9.7 a new command line processor called *Command Line Processor Plus*, or CLPPlus is included, which is designed to be somewhat compatible with the Oracle's SQL*Plus -- it supports all typical DB2 commands as well as the majority of SQL*Plus commands, so it may be a better choice for you.

[More info in the manual](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.clpplus.doc/doc/c0053823.html).

Comment: This looks excellent, similar to Golden which I used to using with Oracle. Unfortunately I'm don't know how to create the "tnsnames.ora equivalent" for DB2 and get the following error when I try to add a target; "SQL1031N The database directory cannot be found on the indicated file system". Here are the (masked) coordinates I was given; "URL: jdbc:db2://FAKE1.FAKE2.COM:446/FAKE3 @mustaccio

Comment: You don't need to create the "tnsnames.ora equivalent", and the proper connection string format is shown in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

The command line equivalent to that would be `db2`

You can use it in two ways

1. IF you issue the command `db2` with no arguments, a shell console will start, letting you connect to a DB2 instance, and then you can execute your SQL commands.

**elk /home/melnyk>db2**

```
db2 => connect to sample

Database Connection Information

Database server        = DB2/6000 8.2.0
SQL authorization ID   = MELNYK
Local database alias   = SAMPLE

db2 => select * from org

DEPTNUMB DEPTNAME       MANAGER DIVISION   LOCATION
      10 Head Office        160 Corporate  New York
      15 New England         50 Eastern    Boston
      20 Mid Atlantic        10 Eastern    Washington
      38 South Atlantic      30 Eastern    Atlanta
      42 Great Lakes        100 Midwest    Chicago
      51 Plains             140 Midwest    Dallas
      66 Pacific            270 Western    San Francisco
      84 Mountain           290 Western    Denver

  8 record(s) selected.


db2 => terminate
DB20000I  The TERMINATE command completed successfully.
```

**elk /home/melnyk>**

2. Alternatively, you can use db2 using arguments directly from command line if you don't want to abandon your current shell.

   > db2 connect to sample
   >
   > db2 select * from org
   >
   > db2 terminate

Both methods will provide the same results, so you can choose the method that fits better to you.

You can find more information about this, on the official [IBM DB2 documentation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0503melnyk/)

Comment: and you can put your sql in a file and type `db2 -f query.sql  > queryoutput.out`

Comment: FYI Cristian is describing the **DB2 Command Line Processor** (as it's called when you install the DB2 client on Windows).  You can use the CLP directly from the command prompt on Windows (as described in point #2) but you have to start the **DB2 Command Window** so that your command prompt is properly initialized.